# How to add multiple experimental option in python selenium webdriver chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'd like to add two experimental_option to the selenium webdriver chrome options. This to run a test in an already open browser window AND with a mobile emulation active. I'm able to do them separately, but I'm not able to make them work at the same time. And now I'm asking myself if it's even possible, maybe not, but it's more likely that I don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance to those who want to give me some advice.

This takes the control of an already open browser window

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = my_path, options = opt)
driver.get(URL)
```

This emulates a mobile, but in a new window

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", { "deviceName": "Pixel 2" })
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = mt_path, options = opt)
driver.get(URL)
```

Trying to make them work together I made a lot of attemps. Here some of them.

Adding twice the option results in an exception regardless of which one I put first:

```
opt.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", { "deviceName": "Pixel 2" })
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
#selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
#from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: mobileEmulation
```

Adding both as arguments results in a TypeError.

```
opt.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", { "deviceName": "Pixel 2"}, "debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
#'TypeError: add_experimental_option() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given'
```

Or I tryed this other way, but it only opens the URL in the already open window with no mobile emulation.

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", { "deviceName": "Pixel 2" })
desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = my_path, desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities(), options = opt)
driver.get(URL)
```

So I have no more ideas, poor me, and I am looking for a suggestion from someone more experienced.

Comment: what version of selenium are you using ?

Comment: Selenium version: 3.141.0  (Python version 3.8.3)

Comment: Same issue for me too. I can only add_experimental_options once. I need to do it twice to set debuggerAddress and some other prefs. debuggerAddress inside of prefs does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This Copied from another thread.I Think it can be done by this

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", 
{"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}) 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 

chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this

chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("start-maximized") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chromeOptions.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=.\cookies\\test") 

b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).